# Intro.js change tooltip position

Tags: javascript, jquery, intro.js

I'm using intro.js for tour on my website. I'm using `bottom` as default tooltip position, but is there a way I can change the position of the tooltip once the tour has started?

Here is my code:

```
tourPluginObject=introJs();
    tourPluginObject.onchange(function(targetElement) {
      if($(targetElement).attr("data-step")==5 && enteredStepFive==false){
        enteredStepFive=true;//I entered a step five, so mark this
        tourPluginObject.setOption('tooltipPosition','left');//Set new tooltip position
        tourPluginObject.setOption('data-position','left');//Set new tooltip position
        tourPluginObject.refresh();//Refresh layout
      }
    });
    tourPluginObject.setOptions({'tooltipPosition': 'bottom' });//Set default tooltip position
    tourPluginObject.start();//Start tour
```

Answer (score 3):

If you can modify the html, you can add the data-attribute `data-position="left"` on element 5, and leave the others without position or set them all to "`bottom`".

This way step5 will have desired position without the need to modify it during runtime.